# Can't instantiate a 2D text in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, I am trying to instantiate a text mesh pro gameobject so that every time the score rises, a clone of the text comes up and indicates the player that he/she has earned a point. But after writing the code and playtesting it, I checked that the text is getting cloned but I also realized that those cloned texts were not visible. Here is the code.

```
public Rigidbody2D plusScore;
public Transform scoreInstancePos;
public void AddScore ()
{
    workProgress += workEfficiency;
    //the indicator
    Rigidbody2D plusInstance;
    plusInstance = Instantiate(plusScore, scoreInstancePos.position, Quaternion.identity) as Rigidbody2D;
    plusInstance.AddForce(scoreInstancePos.up * 1000);
} //Makes it float up
```

Also, this is an android game. Could that be a problem?

Comment: There's a couple different things you can check. Test it in Editor to confirm: the scale of the created instance, its position, its sorting layers/depths. If it's a TextMeshPro UI object, then you're going to have to look into the Canvas sorting, and order of the object in the hierarchy. (Edit): If it's a TMP UI object, make sure you're cloning it into a Canvas too. UI prefabs cloned outside of a canvas don't play well :)

Comment: 1) is it moving up too quickly? 2) does the Text component have a string in it?

Comment: I think it is more optimized and easier to put existed text meshes in hierarchy before runtime into the queue and use them (Pooling). Maybe it doesn't make some of these problems too but if you want to use instantiate after instantiating change its scale according to which you want.

Comment: 99% chance you're simply not spawning them as a child of a Canvas. I can't see anything in your code that would indicate you are doing this (you aren't specifying a parent so your object will spawn as a root object).

Comment: XD I thought that I was instantiating the text inside the canvas because the tab was open and it looked like it was inside the canvas. Thanks so much!